# Slow boot on Ubuntu 15.04 during ACPI

Tags: boot, kernel, 15.04, acpi

The time seems to be wasted mainly between these two log lines. What could it be waiting for ?

```
Apr 30 01:19:22 terodde kernel: [    0.907820] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query honored via cmdline
Apr 30 01:19:22 terodde kernel: [    6.527435] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
```

Further on some more time is spent doing acpi stuff.

```
Apr 30 01:19:22 terodde kernel: [    6.549824] acpi PNP0A03:02: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
Apr 30 01:19:22 terodde kernel: [    8.560340] acpi PNP0A03:02: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug AER]
```

This is on Supermicro X10DAi with E52660v3 processors and newest BIOS. The problem was there with the stock BIOS settings and didn't change with some tweaking. I boot with `acpi_osi=Linux` because the system seems to perform better with it. Unsetting this makes no difference during boot.

Here's the [kern.log](http://pastebin.com/ZdwMKNTy) of the first 16 or so seconds.

It would be of some help, if I knew what the kernel could be waiting for at that time.